# VPN says connected but cannot ping tunnel ip

Tags: vpn, windows-server-2008-r2, gateway

I have a VPN set up on a Symantec Gateway 320 and the status of the VPN is connected but the feature it provides is not working which means it is not actually connected..The only way to test it other than trying to use it in the program that utilizes it is to ping the remote subnet IP we use. mask numbers match, no settings have been changed it just stopped working.

Comment: What kind of vpn is that? Ipsec? SSL?
Is it a lan-to-lan or a client-to-lan vpn?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you do a `ROUTE PRINT` from the command prompt and post it here?  You may not have received a route from the VPN server.